# Invalid Mutability Exception when using background threads in KMM project on iOS

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-native

I am working on a KMM project and am currently developing a model layer. In order to work with data I was planning to create a singleton like so:

```kotlin
@ThreadLocal object Repository {

    private var dao: DataAccessObject? = null

    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)

    fun injectDao(dao: DataAccessObject) {
        scope.async {
            Repository.dao = dao
        }
    }

    suspend fun create(dataObjectType: TypeOfDataObject): DataObject? {
        var dataObject: DataObject? = null

        val job = scope.async {
            dataObject = dao?.create(dataObjectType = dataObjectType)
        }

        job.await()

        return dataObject
    }
}
```

In such implementation as you see the request to the database is handled in `Main` thread, which's quite not good. But it works and the data is returned from the function correctly. The next obvious step is to try to run it in background scope. To make it we should just redeclare `scope`:

```kotlin
private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
```

When we run the code and call `create` function from somewhere it falls with

```
Uncaught Kotlin exception: kotlin.native.concurrent.InvalidMutabilityException: mutation attempt of frozen kotlin.native.internal.Ref@5761ad88
2021-02-02 23:54:50.408645+0300 Plendy[28960:2893398] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
    at 0   Shared                          0x000000010d51640f kfun:kotlin.Throwable#<init>(kotlin.String?){} + 95 (/Users/teamcity/buildAgent/work/f01984a9f5203417/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/Throwable.kt:23:37)
    at 1   Shared                          0x000000010d50f0bd kfun:kotlin.Exception#<init>(kotlin.String?){} + 93 (/Users/teamcity/buildAgent/work/f01984a9f5203417/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/Exceptions.kt:23:44)
    at 2   Shared                          0x000000010d50f32d kfun:kotlin.RuntimeException#<init>(kotlin.String?){} + 93 (/Users/teamcity/buildAgent/work/f01984a9f5203417/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/Exceptions.kt:34:44)
    at 3   Shared                          0x000000010d5448cd kfun:kotlin.native.concurrent.InvalidMutabilityException#<init>(kotlin.String){} + 93 (/Users/teamcity/buildAgent/work/f01984a9f5203417/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/native/concurrent/Freezing.kt:22:60)
    at 4   Shared                          0x000000010d5460af ThrowInvalidMutabilityException + 431 (/Users/teamcity/buildAgent/work/f01984a9f5203417/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/native/concurrent/Internal.kt:92:11)
    at 5   Shared                          0x000000010d6470b0 MutationCheck + 128
    at 6   Shared                          0x000000010d5640f8 kfun:kotlin.native.internal.Ref#<set-element>(1:0){} + 104 (/Users/teamcity/buildAgent/work/f01984a9f5203417/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/native/internal/Ref.kt:12:5)
    at 7   Shared                          0x000000010d4a1d5b kfun:com.plendy.PlendyCore.Model.KNPlendyData.$create$lambda-1COROUTINE$4.invokeSuspend#internal + 779 (/Users/petr/Documents/Projects/Plendy/Android/Plendy/PlendyCore/src/commonMain/kotlin/com/plendy/PlendyCore/Model/KNPlendyData.kt:23:13)
    at 8   Shared                          0x000000010d537958 kfun:kotlin.coroutines.native.internal.BaseContinuationImpl#resumeWith(kotlin.Result<kotlin.Any?>){} + 760 (/Users/teamcity/buildAgent/work/f01984a9f5203417/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/coroutines/ContinuationImpl.kt:30:39)
    at 9   Shared                          0x000000010d6d7a78 kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask#run(){} + 2680 (/opt/buildAgent/work/44ec6e850d5c63f0/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/internal/DispatchedTask.kt:106:71)
    at 10  Shared                          0x000000010d687fb8 kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase#processNextEvent(){}kotlin.Long + 840 (/opt/buildAgent/work/44ec6e850d5c63f0/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/EventLoop.common.kt:274:18)
    at 11  Shared                          0x000000010d6efbbb kfun:kotlinx.coroutines#runEventLoop(kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoop?;kotlin.Function0<kotlin.Boolean>){} + 843 (/opt/buildAgent/work/44ec6e850d5c63f0/kotlinx-coroutines-core/native/src/Builders.kt:80:40)
    at 12  Shared                          0x000000010d6f8d39 kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.WorkerCoroutineDispatcherImpl.start$lambda-0#internal + 409 (/opt/buildAgent/work/44ec6e850d5c63f0/kotlinx-coroutines-core/native/src/Workers.kt:49:17)
    at 13  Shared                          0x000000010d6f8f30 kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.WorkerCoroutineDispatcherImpl.$start$lambda-0$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$35.invoke#internal + 64 (/opt/buildAgent/work/44ec6e850d5c63f0/kotlinx-coroutines-core/native/src/Workers.kt:47:24)
    at 14  Shared                          0x000000010d6f8f90 kfun:kotlinx.coroutines.WorkerCoroutineDispatcherImpl.$start$lambda-0$FUNCTION_REFERENCE$35.$<bridge-UNN>invoke(){}#internal + 64 (/opt/buildAgent/work/44ec6e850d5c63f0/kotlinx-coroutines-core/native/src/Workers.kt:47:24)
    at 15  Shared                          0x000000010d545d59 WorkerLaunchpad + 185 (/Users/teamcity/buildAgent/work/f01984a9f5203417/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/native/concurrent/Internal.kt:69:54)
    at 16  Shared                          0x000000010d64ba4f _ZN6Worker19processQueueElementEb + 3135
    at 17  Shared                          0x000000010d64adf6 _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_113workerRoutineEPv + 54
    at 18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000110a86950 _pthread_start + 224
    at 19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000110a8247b thread_start + 15
```

What is strange that the data is written to the db, meaning that `dao` is called successfully, but data isn't returning from the function, because the exception occurs earlier. At this point I don't understand to what frozen object does the exception relates? What I've tried next is to remove `job.await()` line and it worked perfectly with no exceptions besides of cause having null in function's output.

So my question is: how to make code run in a background thread still having an ability to wait for its output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should include more of the exception info to help figure out what's happening, and you can use `ensureNeverFrozen` to help identify when something is being inadvertently frozen. However, in this case, I think I can figure it out.

In this case, capturing a reference to `dataObject` in your background lambda will freeze it. Trying to reassign it is (probably) throwing your exception.

```kotlin
var dataObject: DataObject? = null

        val job = scope.async {
            //Trying to assign the frozen dataObject will fail
            dataObject = dao?.create(dataObjectType = dataObjectType)
        }
```

Since you're already in a suspend function, why not just use something like `withContext`?

```kotlin
suspend fun create(dataObjectType: TypeOfDataObject): DataObject? {

        val dataObject = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            dao?.create(dataObjectType = dataObjectType)
        }

        return dataObject
    }
```

And if you're going that far ...

```kotlin
suspend fun create(dataObjectType: TypeOfDataObject): DataObject? = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
    dao?.create(dataObjectType = dataObjectType)
}
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for replying. Firstly I have updated the exception log. Secondly I believe that the problem is not with `dao`. The singleton is thread-local thus mutable. In my iOS app's app delegate I am injecting this dependency for the onliest time during the app's life cycle and have no errors. Moreover, I see that the data is written to the database meaning that the `dao` is injected properly. During the `create` execution `dao` is not somehow changing. I also tried to use `withContext` with `Dispatcher.Default` and had the exactly the same error.

Comment: My onliest assumption is that this may be a conflict of different threads. I am calling `create` from iOS's main thread, then it is creating a coroutine in a background thread, which should be somehow handled. If I'm not mistaken there are some limitations for coroutines with starting for one thread from another, or this is not correct?

Comment: Oh, God, my night-mind haven't realized you were speaking about `dataObject`, but not `dao`. Give me some time to try. But still, why is it working properly in `Main` thread then?

Comment: Kevin, seems that the `dataObject` was actually the problem. I've used your advise and now it works perfectly. Thanks!